# 'directive' does not exist in type 'Component'

Tags: angular

[Two components and terminal error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZvDw.jpg)

Basically there are two components, app component and courses component. I wanna use courses component in app component as you can see in the picture. But it's giving me the error visible in terminal.

Comment: The `directives` property was removed in RC-6. You don't need it, just make sure the component you want to use is included in the module's `declarations`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directives are not available in 2.0.0-rc.6 onwards. You will have to add it in **declarations** of AppModule like this-

```
import { CoursesComponent }               from './courses.component';

@NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing, RouterModule ],
    declarations: [ AppComponent, CoursesComponent ],
    providers:    [ appRoutingProviders ],
    bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```